# CE 1.9.2.1 - Extend RWD Menu

Tags: rwd, magento-1.9.2.1

I am working with a copy of the "new" RWD template and I want to extend the header with a new drop down menu left to the "user account" menu.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your template dir and copy/past the following dirs and file in your theme:

> page/html/header.phtml

On line 67 you will see the div  that contains the account menu. You can customize code here.
For more detail see [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/37746/cannot-customize-header-block-by-custom-module)